# VS2010 Disable outlining in xaml, (or disable outlining completely)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 how can I disable outlining in XAML files please? Or even better just disable outlining entirely for everything.

Every time I move the mouse from the editor pane to the Solution Explorer the mouse crosses over that stupid outlining widget and causes half the editor to start flashing, it's the most irritating thing ever.

Comment: Bounty available for a permanent solution in VS 2010, not just Ctrl-M, Ctrl-P.

Comment: Even this ranks after VS egregiously misformatting Javascript in annoyingness.

Comment: Anyone know of a way to fix this for vs2012?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I believe setting

```
<Category name="XAML_Formatting" Category="{dac05320-0c3a-4ead-a332-8c23b0cfc130}" Package="{e58c2a8b-bcc4-4559-ad59-d62eb6d58a22}" RegisteredName="XAML_Formatting" PackageName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xaml">
    <PropertyValue name="AutoOutlining">False</PropertyValue>
</Category>
```

in your Visual Studio settings file (.vssettings) should work.

In order to disable outlining entirely you need to set a few more variables in that file to false.

An example of a vssettings file is avaliable [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~cs3/Misc/CSharp.vssettings), though this isn't a recommended configuration or anything just an example.

`<PropertyValue name="EnterOutliningModeOnOpen">0</PropertyValue>` for the C# and J# sections

`<PropertyValue name="AutoOutlining">False</PropertyValue>` for XML

`<PropertyValue name="Outlining">False</PropertyValue>` for Basic (I presume VB)

The following values for C & C++.

```
<PropertyValue name="EnterOutliningModeWhenFilesOpen">false</PropertyValue>
<PropertyValue name="AutomaticOutliningOfStatementBlocks">false</PropertyValue>
<PropertyValue name="AutomaticOutliningOfPragmaRegions">tfalse</PropertyValue>
```

Regarding the GUI method of turning off outlining for various languages in Visual Studio see [here](http://saraford.net/2005/05/12/did-you-know-how-to-turn-off-outlining-mode/).

Alternately you could implement a custom [language service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165939%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that has outlining disabled and that is set to override all language settings as part of your Visual Studio settings file. Though this approach is probably more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Close enough, I went into that file and changed all options having to do with outlining to False, false, or 0 :-) Definitely worth the bounty.